# Git rebase alias with a one-second delay between each commit

Tags: git, github

Git commit dates are stored as Unix epoch timestamp, i.e., in seconds. When rebasing, multiple commits get the same timestamp. Then they often show up in GitHub in the wrong order (https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-in-the-wrong-order/).

I'd like to have an alias for the `rebase` command that waits a second between each commit. Ideally it would also support the `--interactive` mode.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do this, although if you're using a version of Git in which `git rebase` is still a series of shell scripts, you could modify the scripts.  Now that `git rebase` is mostly in C, it's much more difficult to modify the source to add a delay between commits.  But you could still use the old shell scripts (note that there are several), copying them to your own scripts named `old-rebase` for instance and modifying them to run `old-rebase--am` and `old-rebase--interactive`, and run `git old-rebase` to fire them off.

---

In any case, it's more complicated than you have presented.  Every commit has *two* time stamps: the "author" time stamp and the "committer" time stamp.  To see both, run `git log --pretty=fuller`, for instance (there are other ways to see both but this is the one to start with).

When you run `git rebase` (non-interactive), Git generally<sup>1</sup> preserves the author information: the name, the email address, *and the author time stamp.*  The `--committer-date-is-author-date` flag sets the committer date to the same time stamp as the preserved author date, instead of setting it to "right now".  The `--ignore-date` flag sets the author date to the committer date (i.e., "right now").  Git will always make you the committer.

When you run `git rebase --interactive`, Git uses `git cherry-pick` instead, to implement each `pick` command.  This has no control knobs: it preserves the author information and makes you the committer, so the author date is the original author date, and the committer date is "right now".

When viewing commits, it's up to the viewer (`git log`, or whatever) to present commits in some order.  Since there are *two* dates—author and committer—there's a choice to be made here.  GitHub appears to use the author date in the pull request commit list sort, so the fact that the committer dates are within one second of each other is not actually relevant.

---

<sup>1</sup>I say "generally" here because there are a lot of corner cases, especially with the interactive code and splitting or combining commits.  Note that `git rebase -p` uses the interactive *code* in a non-interactive way, so does not support `--committer-date-is-author-date`.